# Is an infinite loop possible in Unix shell using just redirection and pipelines?

Tags: shell, unix, redirect, infinite-loop, pipeline

This is a pointless task, I know. But I'm just messing around and trying to familiarize myself.

I thought this might work, but no:

```
root@debian: Jibberish 2> file.txt && file.txt < /dev/tty0
```

I thought this might generate an error message which would then be sent to file.txt which would in turn be the input back into the shell (/dev/tty0).

Anyway, if anyone knows how to make an infinite loop using just redirects and pipelines I'd be interested to know.

Thanks

Comment: `exec 2>&0` is a more direct way of redirecting your stderr to stdin... which is not to say that it'll have the effect that you want here.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

```
root@debian: yes
y
y
...
^C
root@debian:
```

;-)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be done in several ways, one is like that:

```
cat < /dev/zero > /dev/null
```